# How to get logged in user Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I can get build user in Jenkins pipeline (using build user var plugin). But I can't get logged in user. Please see below script

```
stage('Manual Approval') 
      {
          steps {
              script {
                  def userInput
                  try {
                      userInput = input(id: 'Proceed1', message: 'Do you want to approve this step ?', parameters: [[$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: true, description: '', name: 'Please confirm you agree with this' ]])
                  } catch (err)
                  {
                      def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
                      userInput = false
                      echo "Aborted by: [${user}]"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

And here is log of Jenkins

```
Input requested
Approved by admin
```

How can I get the user name "admin" in this case (if the value of input is true) ? When I use the function User.current().getId(), it always return SYSTEM

In my case, I want to check logged in user whether has correct permission or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are asking but it sounds like you want the id of the user who approved the input step.

If that is the case then you can use the **submitterParameter** property of the input step. You will find it in the input step doco (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) and under Pipeline Syntax in Jenkins.

This is what it would look like in your example:

```
def userInput = input(id: 'Proceed1', 
  submitterParameter: 'submitter', 
  message: 'Do you want to approve this step ?', 
  parameters: [booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description:'',name: 'Please confirm you agree with this'])

println userInput.submitter
```

Note that if you didn't have any other parameters in the input step then the return value would be the submitter user id directly instead of a map as is the case above.

Comment: Great, that is my need. Many thanks @Lionel Orellana